# Проблема с SSL сертификатом

Tags: https, ssl, openssl

Проблема в то, что проверка на ssllabs.com дает оценку А+, но при попытке зайти на сайт все равно выскакивает сообщение не защищено с NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Проверялось с очищенным кэшем, куками, в режиме инкогнито. С разных компов. Браузер Хром. При этом где-то открывается, но с пометкой в инфо небезопасное соединение и без загрузки "опасных скриптов".

debian 8.3;
openssl 1.0.1t;
nginx 1.6.2;
php-fpm;

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть ссылку на сайт...

Comment: в данный момент там ssl отключен, так как это критично.

Comment: Без просмотра ссылки трудно будет угадать в чём проблема, т.к могут быть множественные причины которые трудно просто описать в ответе, если возможно на несколько минут включите SSL и дайте ссылку для проверки

Comment: Скинь лог nginx, там фиксироваться должна эта ошибка.

Comment: intermediate сертификат не забыли добавить?

Comment: Кусок лога -  2017/02/03 14:11:06 [error] 32761#0: send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53      И таких ошибок море

Comment: Вот ваша же ошибка, тут и решение в первом ответе http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892873/ssl-cert-err-cert-authority-invalid-on-mobile-chrome-only

Comment: Я брал сертификат на startssl.com мне был выдан ssl.crt, ssl.key server.pem и ssl.csr. Я так понимаю, что server.pem и есть промежуточный? Если да, то я про него не забыл. Объединил с ssl.crt. Проверка на A+

Comment: @PavelOrlov когда решитесь включить SSL и показать ссылку, дайте знать, проверим...

Comment: @Arsen включил. Сайт good-wheels.ru

Comment: сейчас проверю.

Comment: После проверки стало ясно что Google Сhrome не принимает Digital Signature, Key Encipherment  вашего SSL сертификата, думаю данную проблему смогут решить только саппорт  StartCom, напишите им, они смогут заново сгенерировать и выслать вам новый сертификат.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую с ними связаться. А если я просто перезакажу сертификат это поможет?

Comment: В любом случае вы должны им описать проблему! т.к у них что то не так )) может что то при генерации не так пошло.. Но с ними обсудите данную проблему. Не забудьте написать что проблема исходит от  "Digital Signature, Key Encipherment "

Comment: @Arsen спасибо за помощь

Comment: StartCom (StartSSL и WoSign) как минимум два раза подрывал доверие к себе нехорошими действиями, поэтому их сертификатам теперь никто не доверяет и про них нужно забыть

Answer (score 1):

У меня было такое. Отсутствовали сертификаты промежуточных центров. И хотя сам по себе сертификат `cloudlfare` (в моем случае) валидный, путь к корневому центру сертификации браузер найти не мог.

Для решения проблемы в конец файла `/etc/nginx/ssl/site.pem` (который содержал сертификат `cloudflare`) я добавил содержимое `cloudflare-intermediate.pem`, после чего все заработало.

Comment: У меня в конечном site.pem получается 3 сертификата: основной, промежуточный и третий. Все верно?

Comment: У меня сейчас установлено два сертификата: сайта (выданный cloudflare) и промежуточный. Корневой указывать не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло( Убрал корневой...

Comment: а промежуточный-то оставили? И что Chrome пишет в консоли на вкладке Security?

Comment: Промежуточный оставил. Пишет ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: При этом по порверкам A+

Comment: Что в консоли браузера, на вкладке security?

Comment: ну так все в порядке уже: http://take.ms/EKi7X

Comment: забавно, а у меня все равно ненадежный))) и в косоли Certificate Error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

Comment: ну я сразу сказал - не хватает промежуточных сертификатов. Надо копать цепочку

Comment: А как же так может быть, что у вас он надежный, а у меня нет?

Comment: Мой браузер, значит, хранит у себя тот промежуточный сертификат, которого вам не хватает.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из сапорта StartSsl:

Hello,

All certificates issued before 21.10.2016 are not affected. Certificates issued after 21.10.2016 are distrusted in Chrome, Firefox and Safari browsers.

Official document about distrust > https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/

We are working hard on remediation plan, and we are doing everything to regain trust ASAP. One of the steps already fully done.

We have some delays with an interim solution but will have more information only later in February.

Please accept our apologies for the inconvenience.

Собственно все с ними понятно. Знает кто еще сервисы хорошие (желательно free)?

Comment: Cloudflare - бесплатный сертификат на 15 лет

Comment: Let's Encrypt же, как можно не знать